# Every single XML parser I tried doesn't work with this specific XML

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

index.js

```
const fs = require("node:fs")
const xml2js = require('xml2js')

const parser = new xml2js.Parser()

const data = fs.readFileSync('test.xml', "utf8")
const json = JSON.parse(await parser.parseStringPromise(data))

console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
```

test.xml

```
<thing>
    <2 value="300.0"/>
    <3 value="1.0"/>
</thing>
```

All of this only returns this error:

```
Error: Unencoded <
Line: 1
Column: 3
Char: 2
```

I've been stuck trying to figure out what is wrong for hours straight, I tried 3 xml2json, xml2js and xml-js. None of them worked and they return the same error.

Comment: You need to think about why this took you so long and how you can improve your problem-solving skills. What reference materials did you turn to, and how did you use them? Trying different XML parsers to see if any of them give better diagnostics than the others isn't a totally bad strategy, but I would turn first to the spec. Oxygen gives a rather unhelpful error message, but it locates very precisely the line and character position that are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is invalid. An XML element name cannot start with a number.

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn

> The first character of a [Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) must be a [NameStartChar](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar), and any other characters must be [NameChars](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar); this mechanism is used to prevent names from beginning with European (ASCII) digits or with basic combining characters. Almost all characters are permitted in names, except those which either are or reasonably could be used as delimiters. The intention is to be inclusive rather than exclusive, so that writing systems not yet encoded in Unicode can be used in XML names. See J Suggestions for XML Names for suggestions on the creation of names.

Comment: While you are correct, the `unencoded` error implies that there are other issues as well.

Comment: The error "Unencoded <" is the parser making a guess that the "<" was intended as a literal "<" rather than as the beginning of a start or end tag. Unfortunately it's hard to get this right: messages that guess at intent are very helpful if the guess is correct, and very unhelpful if it's wrong. I've taken to designing error messages so the guess is more tentative: something like "Perhaps you intended `&lt;`".